# Probability that a second item drawn from the same lot will be defective,given that the first item is returned to the lot after it has been checked.

Tags: probability

There are two lots of items,it is known that all the items of one lot satisfy the technical standards and $\frac{1}{4}$th of the items of the other lot are defective.Suppose that an item from one of the lot,selected at random turns out to be good.What is the probability that a second item drawn from the same lot will be defective,given that the first item is returned to the lot after it has been checked.

---

Since the lot $A$ has all good and no defective items and the lot $B$ has $\frac{3}{4}$th good and $\frac{1}{4}$th defective items.
Probability that the first item drawn is good is $\frac{1}{2}\times1+\frac{1}{2}\times \frac{3}{4}$.

The probability that a second item drawn from the same lot,from which first was drawn, will be defective is
Case$(i)$Either the first item was drawn from lot $A$,so the second item will be drawn from lot $A$.Its probability$=\frac{1}{2}\times1\times 0$
Case$(ii)$Or the first item was drawn from lot $B$,so the second item will be drawn from lot $B$.Its probability$=\frac{1}{2}\times\frac{3}{4}\times \frac{1}{4}$
Then i added the above probabilities but the correct answer is not coming.

I dont know what is the right way to solve it,please guide me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $G$ be the event the first drawn item is good, and let $D$ be the event that the second drawn item is defective. We want the probability of $D$ *given* that $G$ occurred. So we want the  **conditional probability** $\Pr(D\mid G)$.

By the definition of conditional probability, we have
$$\Pr(D\mid G)=\frac{\Pr(G\cap D)}{\Pr(G)}.$$
You computed $\Pr(G)$ correctly. It remains to find $\Pr(G\cap D)$.

The event $G\cap D$ occurs if we drew from the lot that has defectives, got a good, then got a defective. The probability of this is $(1/2)(3/4)(1/4)$.

Now we know $\Pr(G\cap D)$ and $\Pr(G)$. Divide.